# theorem about equivalence of metrics, the $d$-ball is a $p$-open set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I need some help on proving a theorem about topologically equivalent metrics.

It seems that somehow I am missing a final but vital step on the proof, so I am going to write the theorem and represent my attempt to prove it.

> **Theorem:**
>
> Consider a non empty set $\mathbb{X}$ and two metrics $\mathrm{d},p$ over $\mathbb{X}$, such that, there are two constants $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ so
>
> $$k_1d(x,y)\leq p(x,y) \leq k_2d(x,y) \, \,\,\forall x,y \in \mathbb{X} $$
>
> Prove that the metrics $d$ and $p$ are equivalent.

*My attempt*

---

$d \sim p \iff  \tau(d)=\tau(p) \iff $ every $d$-open set is also a $p$-open set and vice versa.

But if we consider that every $d$-open set is a union of $d$-(open)balls,
we have just to prove that

every $p$-ball is $d$-open set and vice versa.

In order to prove that every $p$-ball is $d$-open set
we have to prove that 
$$\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{X}, \forall r>0, \forall x :\! x \in B_p(x_0,r)\, \exists \varepsilon(x)=\varepsilon>0 :\forall y \in B_d(x,\varepsilon)\Rightarrow y \in B_p(x_0,r) $$

So, let $x_0$ be a point of $\mathbb{X}$ and $r>0$ be a real number,
consider now the $p$-ball

$$B_p(x_0,r)=\left\{ x: p(x_0,x)<r \right\}$$

For every $x \in B_p(x_0,r)$ we want to find a $\varepsilon>0$ so

$$
( \, \forall y \in B_d(x,\varepsilon) \Rightarrow y \in B_p(x_0,r)\, ) \iff
( \, \forall y: d(x,y)< \varepsilon \Rightarrow p(x_0,y)<r \, )
$$

We have that

$$ \begin{align}  p(x_0,y) &\leq k_2 d(x_0,y) \\ &\leq k_2d(x_0,x)+k_2d(x,y) \\ &< k_2d(x_0,x)+k_2\varepsilon
\end{align} $$

we want to 
$$ k_2d(x_0,x)+k_2\varepsilon \leq r  \Rightarrow  \varepsilon \leq \frac{r-k_2d(x_0,x)}{k_2}$$

So finally it seems that if we choose $\displaystyle \varepsilon \leq \frac{r-k_2d(x_0,x)}{k_2}$ we are done, but we need to ensure that

$$\varepsilon > 0 \Rightarrow r-k_2d(x_0,x)>0$$

**That is my problem,** how to prove that $r-k_2d(x_0,x)>0$

---

If my hole attempt of proving that theorem is wrong, could you suggest me another strategy to prove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is the right thing but I cannot see why you are making it so convoluted. One thing I see is that you seem to be trying to find one $\varepsilon$ for l $y$, which doesn't make sense.

If $y\in B_p(X_0,r)$, then there exists $s>0$ with $B_p(y,s)\subset  B_p(x_0,r)$ (this is just the fact that balls are open, which follows from the triangle inequality). Now you just notice that $B_d(y,s/k_2)\subset B_p(y,s)$.

Comment: Ok so first I have to use the fact that d-ball is a d-open set, but I cannot understand what doesn't make sense in my attempt

Comment: You seem to look for a $\varepsilon$ that does not depend on $y$, when in reality it definitely has to depend on $y$.